# Golang :command line argument with -> charecter

Tags: go, command-line

I need to accept command line argument to run a Go program in the below format:

```
 go run app.go 1->A
```

I am using `os.Args[1]`. But it only accepts till '1-' . '>A' is being skipped.

Any help to resolve this issue is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shell is interpreting the `>` as IO [redirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)).  The shell opened the file `A` as standard output for the command and passed the argument `1-` to the command.

Quote the argument to avoid this:

```
go run app.go "1->A"
```